# Pick closest NSNumber from array

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, nsnumber

I have an array with a bunch of `NSNumber`s. From an `UISlider` I get a certain value when the user stops dragging it. I would like to get the closes number from the array.

So for instance, if the user drags the `UISlider` to `13`, and the `NSArray` contains the `NSNumbers` with `10` and `15`; I want to get `15` from the array.

Example of array:

```
NSArray *values = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:15],
                    [NSNumber numberWithInt:20],
                    [NSNumber numberWithInt:30],
                    [NSNumber numberWithInt:45],
                    [NSNumber numberWithInt:60],
                    [NSNumber numberWithInt:90],
                    [NSNumber numberWithInt:110], nil];
```

How do I get the correct number from the array?

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Why not calculate the difference of the value to every element in the array and use the absolute value to decide which is the closest?

Comment: Of course, I could do that. But what if I have an array with 1000 values? Thats quite some calculating and memory usage.

Comment: Array iteration is quite effective in Objective-C. I use it a lot without performance issues. Try it with 1000 values and decide if it is fast enough. Solutions only have to be good enough.

Comment: I disagree. That statement solely depends on the requirements of the project. Generally I believe "good enough" is not a solution unless it is not sustainable. Hence if the array in 6 months would be 100.000 for some reason, it might not be sustainable.

Comment: You are thinking about a slider with 100.000 different discrete values? Sounds strange.

Comment: Check if your number is already in array, if so then that's your answer, if not then add it, now sort array by smallest to largest with OBJ-C built in algorithms, next find location of your number (index) and check just the value above it (index+1) and the value below it (index-1), subtract, absolute value, if value1 < value2 || Lastly remove your number from the array (removeObjectAtIndex)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In your post, the array is sorted.  If it's always sorted, you can use binary search.  `NSArray` has a convenient method for that:

```
CGFloat targetNumber = mySlider.value;
NSUInteger index = [values indexOfObject:@(targetNumber)
    inSortedRange:NSMakeRange(0, values.count)
    options:NSBinarySearchingFirstEqual | NSBinarySearchingInsertionIndex
    usingComparator:^(id a, id b) {
        return [a compare:b];
    }];
```

Now there are four possibilities:

1. Every element of `values` is larger than `targetNumber`: `index` is zero.
2. Every element of `values` is smaller than `targetNumber`: `index` is `values.count`.
3. `values` contains `targetNumber`: `index` is the index of `targetNumber` in `values`.
4. `index` is the index of the smallest element of `values` that is greater than `targetNumber`.

I've cleverly listed the cases in the order we'll handle them.  Here's case 1:

```
if (index == 0) {
    return [values[0] floatValue];
}
```

Here's case 2:

```
if (index == values.count) {
    return [[values lastObject] floatValue];
}
```

We can handle cases 3 and 4 together:

```
CGFloat leftDifference = targetNumber - [values[index - 1] floatValue];
CGFloat rightDifference = [values[index] floatValue] - targetNumber;
if (leftDifference < rightDifference) {
    --index;
}
return [values[index] floatValue];
```

Comment: Works like a charm, except for the fact it should be `[values[0] floatValue]`. Also seems sustainable.

Answer (score 2):

If your `values` array is in order and you always want the value just larger than (or equal to) the entered value you could do something like this:

```
NSInteger count = 0;
do {
    count++;
} while (enteredNum > [values[count] intValue]);

// Do something with [values[count] intValue]
```

Comment: Ok, however; that would mean that if I get 11 I would get 15, and not 10... which is not the nearest number, hence unfortunately not the answer to my question.

Comment: So keep track of the previous and the larger, afterwards compare them with each other.

Comment: This will crash if `enteredNum` is larger than the maximum value, so maybe just applicable in this particular situation with the slider constraint.